# How can I use Interface type object in Grails Domain Class

Tags: grails, interface, dependency-injection, dependencies, code-injection

in Grails, Domain class's variable mapping with database table.

I want use Interface type object. and I want to use Dependency Injection.

Please help me! I don't want to mapping with database table!

```
class User{
  String name
  UserService userService
}

interface UserService{
}
```

If use this code, I can meet the Error Message.
"Can't mapping UserService"

Answer (score 1):

You need to [mark it as `transient`](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html)

```
class User{
  String name
  UserService userService
  static transients = ['userService']
}
```